# Verify certificate with Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a script in Python to download PDFs. It works fine except when I want to access my university's pages which need a certificate.

My question is: how do I "show" the page that I have the correct certificate before I download? My code looks like this:

```
import urllib

def downloadPDF(url):
    webFile = urllib.urlopen(url)
    localFile = open("myPDF.pdf", "wb")
    localFile.write(webFile.read())
    webFile.close()
    localFile.close()
```

So, when after I try to use `urllib.urlopen(url)`, I would guess that I need something to tell the system that I have the correct certificate. What is the best way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: What error are you getting when you access the secure page?

Comment: No error when I try to access the page -- it's just not possible to open the PDF. It says there was a decoding error.

Comment: Have you opened the downloaded file to see if you can tell what kind of file it is?

Comment: Well, it can't be opened. It is a pdf with 0 bytes... It's empty.

Comment: seems using httplib.HTTPSConnection directly allows to send a client certificate with the request: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/117004-ssl-client-authentication-over-https/